# How to put checkboxes side by side Django Form

Tags: python, css, django, django-forms, modelform

I'm using Django and I need to present a ModelForm with some checkboxes in my template.
The problem is that the checkboxes are in a vertical line, one after another. I need them to be evenly distributed in my page, for example 3 columns containing 4 checkboxes each. At the moment I only have 1 column with all my checkboxes inside it. This creates a scroll and the page looks awful.

I've tried adding CSS classes and IDs as widgets in my "forms.py" file, I can change some styles, but I can't "play" with columns and lines.

Is it possible to do this using Model Forms?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to do it through CSS. Setting the checkbox inputs to inline might work depending on your design.

You can also check out the layout options in Django Crispy Forms: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html

Comment: I'll take a look at Django Crispy and I'll keep this post updated. Thanks!